# How to store all user settings in one database with a unique id

Tags: sql, database, unique, setting

Im making an app where I have a server-side sql database to store the user settings of all users.
Im not sure how to make each user unique, so that the database knows who is who.
The database is storing these user data for each row: id, email, county, age and gender.
So im thinking the best way is to make the user unique to he/she's email - which is unique - so that the when the settings are updated or outputted, the sql knows what row to fetch.

How should I go about with this?
And how would i then output the right data to the right user?

Answer (score 1):

An entity in the database should have a primary key. I understand that in your design the `id` field is going to be the primary key. Usually this is an auto-generated integer. This is called a [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) In this case you need to tell to the table that the email field must be unique as well. You can do that by creating a unique index for this field. The unique index will prevent the creation of two different users with the same email. Going with this approach you can query the table checking either for `id` or for `email`.

An alternative is to have [natural key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key). In this case, email would be the primary key of your table, so you wouldn't have the `id` field. Going with this approach you can query the table checking either for `email`, which is the unique identifier of each user.

Comment: thanks for your inputs nakosspy.
What i cant figure out is how will the app know what email to query from?

Comment: Which design will you go, with surrogate or natural key?

Comment: Well, right now my db is setup up like the surrogate - so i think that one :)

Comment: If you create the unique index then you will never have two different users with the same email. You whenever you need to search for a user, you can search either with its id or with its email, but you don't need to check if another user has the same email, the unique index will do that for you

Comment: I see. But I want the app to remember the users settings. So the app should know what data to either query or update if they are changed..

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you application is doing it's difficult to provide more help. Usually an application keeps a reference to the user object that was created during login. Then you can have a screen that lets the user change settings. In this case all you need to do is update the record with the specified id.